# Suggestions for Winter Bash 2017

Tags: discussion, winter-bash, winter-bash-2017

Winter Bash 2016 is not over yet (it started later than usual this year and will end later than usual), but after noticing that the corresponding versions of this question for [Winter Bash 2015](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272294/what-should-we-do-for-winterbash-2016) and [Winter Bash 2014](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246533/winter-bash-closing-remarks-ideas-for-next-year) were posted on Jan 4 2016 and Jan 4 2015 respectively,  I figured it would be fitting to post this year's version on Jan 4 2017.

Please post your suggestions regarding how to make Winter Bash 2017 even more fun than Winter Bash 2016.

- New suggestions for hats and hat triggers (either regular or secret ones)
- Which hats should be kept?
- Which hats should be retired?
- Do we want more secret Hats?
- Do we want more secret hats that don't get triggered until long after the start of Winter Bash?

Let's keep the traditional format of one suggestion per answer, so people can vote on individual suggestions.

See also: [Winter Bash wrap-up on the SO blog](http://stackoverflow.blog/2017/01/say-farewell-to-winter-bash-2016/?cb=1)

Comment: Have we ever had a hat for asking a HNQ?

Answer (score 70):

### Keep cross-site hats

This year there were two hats, Polymath and Running Ragged, for non-trivial participation on multiple sites.  A few years ago there was a hat for asking (or answering?) on a new-to-you site at some score threshold (don't remember the details).  Hats like these encourage breadth, which is good -- Stack Exchange has more than 160 sites, with new ones being added all the time.  It's easy to lose track of other great sites on the network, either because we didn't even know about them or because we used to participate there and gradually lost touch.

So let's keep doing something along these lines.  It should be more than "show up and vote once", and it should encourage contributing to the core Q&A.  I don't think a hat for, say, reviewing on three different sites would be as valuable as one for providing good questions or answers.

Comment: I disagree. These hats discourage users who don't have a wide range of knowledge. For instance, at first I didn't mind having the What's Up Doc and The NeverEnding Story hats, but after seeing Running Ragged and Polymath I realized: What is the likelihood of me getting those hats (Running Ragged and Polymath)? What about those people who aren't on SO and don't have any knowledge of programming?

Comment: @CalebKleveter Polymath required an upvoted answer on each of three different sites.  (I"m not sure what score was required, but it wasn't high.)  That's achievable.  Yes, Running Ragged was harder, but so are gold badges, or getting an answer to a tumbleweed actually accepted.  (As for the SO hats, my suggestion is about multi-site hats, which those aren't, so I'm not sure why you're bringing those up here.)

Answer (score 67):

## [Flip the hats!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/289118/allow-the-flipping-of-winter-bash-hats)

The hats can only be rotated or moved. But for some avatars, the hat may look better (at discretion of the hat and avatar owner) if the hat was flipped over. This would make hat wearing so much cooler and make our avatars look even cooler (no Winter pun intended).

For example, take my current hat (Like Clockwork) on my Double 0-Minion avatar. The gear is next to the eye, but my Minion would look more spy-like with the gear *over* the eye. Only possible with hat flipping.

[image]

Comment: Flip your avatar.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft But I would have to flip it constantly depending on the hat

Answer (score 50):

### Add a hat for finding duplicates

Can we have a hat that you get if you find, say 10, duplicates and the questions are successfully closed as a result of your 'possible duplicate suggestion'?

Note: this would only be awarded if **you** found the dupe, not if you voted to close as a dupe.

It would also be interesting to see some statistics next year relating to this hat if it was added. If it turns out that this has increased dupe finding, or made it quicker, *maybe* this could be considered into making a badge.

Comment: This would be nice if it could scale based on site size. 10 may be reasonable on really high-volume sites but some sites, even one or two would be difficult to come by, let alone ten.

Comment: @Catija a lot of badges are less accessible on small sites, especially the moderation ones.

Comment: @StephenLeppik but you have an infinite time to get a badge and only ~2 weeks for hats.

Comment: Nice idea; if approved will use to improve my question [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274353/reward-3k-reputation-users-for-finding-duplicates).

Answer (score 44):

## Sportsmanship Hat

I'm a big fan of the sportsmanship badge.  It'd be nice to have a hat to honor those that are good sports and up vote competing answers.

Maybe something like. Up vote competing answer on five questions in which both your answer and the one up  voted have a positive score.

Answer (score 43):

## Don't bring Archimedes back

I haven't missed the secret hat for correctly guessing a secret hat.  There's still an appropriate amount of secret-hat research going on, but it's taking place in a more controlled environment and isn't generating as much angst, as far as I can tell.  That's a win.  Thanks!

Comment: Don't worry about that. I don't believe guessing secret hats for a hat will come back.

Comment: That was Eureka, not Archimedes, if I recall right.

Comment: @AdamLear I believe it was called Archimedes last year but it was the same thing as Eureka. Any of those hats for guessing secret hats, whatever the name is, are done.

Comment: I agree with this. In the prestigious contest to Get All The Hats or get the most on the network, this one meant the only people who could possibly achieve that were these ~40 -- if they were even interested in competing for that. That kind of knockout bottleneck is something I'm happy to see go.

Comment: Incidentally I see this year has 4 all-the-hats competitors; I remember previous years only having one individual (and one year had *nobody*). I'm happier with it this way.

Answer (score 37):

### Design request: hats, not masks

[accessibility](/questions/tagged/accessibility)

The hats this year are really spiffy -- great job on the graphics!  But the "natural size" of some of them fills most of the user image, making it hard to tell people apart graphically.  These are all active users on the same site:

[image: 1] [image: 2] [image: 3] [image: 4]

Yeah, they're all different because of what leaks out around the edges, but it turns out that's not enough to help me recognize individuals, particularly in chat.

The following two have been slightly enlarged by the users, but even at their natural sizes they hide a lot.  I've definitely seen other cases of these two at original sizes concealing identity:

[image: sun hat] [image: Darth hat]

It's possible to shrink and move them so you can still see who's under there, I know, but in my experience this is uncommon:

[image: small Darth]

Other hats manage to be big or "full-featured" without hiding as much, like these two:

[image: 24] [image: hatter]

I know that user avatars are accompanied by names and we can just read the text, but the avatars help, more than I realized.  Can we design hats that let more show through while still having awesome art?

Comment: You could make it so users can stretch the hats.

Comment: @CalebKleveter: Hat are stretchable and shrinkable just now (Ckick on show controls and move the controls around. Rotation and shrink are on the same control). In fact, you can make the "masks" small enough to keep your Avatar recognisable. For my part, I enjoy the masks.

Comment: @jknappen that's been a feature since winter bash started this year

Comment: @jknappen Right. I meant more of making it wider but not tall and vis versa.

Comment: The Batman mask from last year was still decently useable, though it's narrower (especially compared to that big yellow mask) and mostly only takes up significant space in the top portion of the avatar where the hat would be anyway.

Comment: @doppelgreener that's a good point; hats that bias away from the center work better even if they're big.

Answer (score 35):

I would like to suggest

**Stealing Hat**

This hat would be awarded for answering a question that already has an accepted answer and having OP change the acceptance to the new answer.

Also, perhaps some other sort of bonus hat for receiving more upvotes than the original answer.  Just a thought.

I'm proposing that this stealing hat be called "The Steeler" and have the logo of the American Football team, the Pittsburgh Steelers.

[image]

I thought that the "Fiery" tag was really cool this year and I just thought that it would be cool to incorporate different logos and such.

Comment: Possibly for branding purpose this won't be added, but I do like the idea. Maybe something for the same purpose with a similar (but not copyright-infringing) image/logo?

Comment: @EᴀsᴛᴇʀʟʏIʀᴋ I don't really know.  I'm pretty sure that it can be used as long as it's not for profit.  Unless SE has a copyright on Guy Fieri's face :P. But, I know that it's called "Fiery" so maybe that's how they can do it.  It also doesn't have to have that logo, it's just a suggestion :)

Comment: I think there was already a hat with that trigger on 2013 or 2014.

Comment: @Eran Hmmm...I wonder if they could bring it back :)

Comment: We [never recycle hat ideas](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/289380/3-tumbleweeds-no-lifesaver) @steelersquirrel

Comment: @bluefeet Oh, okay.  Well, it was worth a shot.  Thanks for the information :)

Comment: @steelersquirrel that was a joke... they do it all the time.

Comment: @Eran, I think that hat for stealing a checkmark was a pirate hat.

Comment: @bluefeet nobody notice same goods in different packing ;)

Comment: Good idea for a hat, not sold on having the logo of a football team (especially as 'Steeler' is a reference to Steelworkers, not thieves) :-)

Comment: @Robotnik Yeah... I was just trying to do a play on words :)

Comment: I would have preferred a ski mask and grapple hook for the hat :)

Comment: @BrianReichle Well,  I am a die-hard Steelers fan.  So, I was trying to incorporate that into my idea.  I was already told that the logo probably can't be used.  So, if this idea gets used, then it will be something else, anyways ;)

Comment: The idea of having a bonus on a hat is pretty nice - e.g. you could earn a hat and then if you do something else to get the bonus, you get a feather on the same hat.

Answer (score 31):

### Tag: You're It

Tag wikis don't get a lot of love.  Edits don't bump them anywhere, so when people *do* put effort into building them out it often goes unnoticed.  But good tag wikis benefit a site; there's only so much you can express in the 25 characters of a tag name or even the couple hundred characters of a tag summary.  The wiki itself is where you can provide more information, cross-reference related tags, link to canonical questions, and so on.  Not all tag wikis call for this treatment, but I suspect most sites have a few.  (Mine do.)

A hat for making a substantial edit to a tag wiki (including creating one) would remind people that this feature exists.  Since wikis can't be voted on I'm not sure how to set a quality threshold; obviously we don't want it to just be based on size or people will blather in pursuit of character count.  I don't have a good answer for this part.

Comment: On the other side of the coin, the fact that these edits don't really appear anywhere and go unnoticed (other than to the few people who review it) makes me not want to really encourage a bunch of random hat seekers from spamming crappy edits onto them. Tag wikis need better oversight before we could encourage something like that. We already get plenty of people who plagiarize text from other sources who are trying to game the tag wiki editing badges quickly and easily, and it can be really hard to track.

Comment: @animuson good point.  I'd like better oversight for tag wikis regardless of hats.  Do you think we could at least get a "recently updated tag wikis" link on the 10k tools page?  That's not great but it's *something*, and not as hard as figuring out a real UI.

Answer (score 28):

## Add hats for meta participation

We currently have what seems to be 1 hat ("I am Your Father") for meta participation. This seems really sad as this seems to encourage users to focus more about posting and other relevant actions on the main site. But meta is important to since it helps users deal with the inner problems with the site! Thus, I suggest hats for participating for meta. Two such hats would be:

- Answer three questions on meta, all accepted with positive score
- Ask three questions on meta, all with positive score

Since the activity and the importance of a post is debatable and not always represented by score, I also suggest:

- Participate in meta for five days

Comment: The problem with having score-related meta posts is that voting is different on Meta... this means that sometimes, heavily downvoted posts, whether questions or answers, are still very useful. I think that encouraging voting on meta or general meta participation (check meta daily for X days) might be just as good for getting some meta activity.

Comment: @Catija voting is different on meta, yes, but we should still expect more positive-scored posts than negative-scored ones (at least on the sites I'm active on), so making a hat be based on positive-scored meta posts doesn't  seem like it interferes with meta patterns.  You're not being penalized for *also* having negative-scored posts.

Comment: This hat should be ***one*** question and answer at most, I think. It could wreak havoc on smaller sites' metas. I am active on RPG.SE, which has a slow-moving but *very* well-used meta. It's active when it needs to be and people say only what needs to be said. I don't want it to have (3 x number of hat-hunters) questions pour in over the course of Winterbash people are asking merely to get a hat. Encouraging meta participation would be laudable, but we also have to consider what would happen if lots of people do *exactly* what the hat asks.

Answer (score 26):

#### Add a general hat for starting (or awarding?) a bounty

We had a [holiday bountapalooza](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/4186/627) on Worldbuilding as a kind of year-end celebration, and over two dozen questions received bounties totaling over 2,500 reputation points. It's not yet over, but it's been a huge success, and I think encouraging bounties would be fun and extremely productive for the site. Also, the idea of gift-giving fits in well with the various holidays that fall during Winter Bash, including Christmas and Hanukkah.

We did have a bounty-based hat this year ([Philanthropist](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/philantropist)) for awarding a bounty on the last day of Winter Bash. Perhaps a more general one - or even one based on how large a bounty was placed - could attract more encouraged generosity.

**Hat name suggestion:** [Boba Fett](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boba_Fett) (in keeping with the [*Star Wars* tradition](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/i-am-your-father)).

Comment: Fantastic Idea! ;)

Comment: I agree with this completely! In fact it's that seasonal spirit of gift-giving that had me actively hunt out several bounties to place on this Winterbash and the last one (now that I was at 20k+ reputation on my primary site), even without a hat. I'd love to see others doing this too.

Answer (score 24):

Whether from a bug or not, I really liked how some of the hats were not available at the start of the WB. I'm not talking about just the "do X on the solstice" hat, or "vote on the 6th" hat.

**Next year have hats without any specific date trigger, only available starting X days after the bash.**

This would have a number of side effects:

- It would keep the bash lively all throughout, and everybody guessing
- It would stump secret hat guessers (me included)
- It would teach patience :)

Now without any Archimedes hat, this is a great way to have some of the secret hats, especially the easier ones.

Comment: I liked how we instantly got the 2017 hat the moment the bash started. shame it was revoked...

Comment: It wasn't a bug @X-27, it was a way to get users excited for the new year hat.

Comment: Well, the "search three days in a row" and "rep cap three times" hats weren't available on the first couple days. :-) . But yeah, last year there was a secret hat that only triggered on Fridays (not the first day of WB), and a secret date-specific one; those were fun.

Answer (score 22):

Keep hats for reviewing **old contributions**.

This was one of the most beneficial features of this year's Winter Bash that old posts got some new attention: Answers, edits, resurrection of hidden gems, or closing of bad old posts long forgotten.

Comment: Instead of simply reviewing, I would emphasize *improving*. For example, edit an old post that later gets upvoted (suggesting that the edit improved it in some way).

Answer (score 21):

## Community Hats!

There is only one hat for the *community* participating, "Just Here for the Hat". Sure, 20 unique hats is pretty difficult, but the community should also earn hats *together* for other actions. I mean, a community is based on its actions as a *whole* rather than its individual users who top the leader boards in rep and probably hats.

Some ideas would be helpful since I'm a little stuck... but I'll put some that came out of my head:

- Earn 10,000 rep cumulatively (probably secret hat)
- Create five community wiki posts that have at least seven different contributors and a positive score
- Collect all non-secret hats (definitely a secret hat)

Comment: so these would be hats that all the users on a site, where the site meets some trigger, would get the hat?

Comment: @David That's correct

Comment: Community wiki posts? meh. The rest seems cool, but it should be closer to 100.000 rep I guess. 1000 votes seem easy to achieve from one community.

Comment: @Martin but not in small beta communities

Answer (score 18):

I would like to search for users who wear a specific hat.

The reason: when I wear hats, I will consider how I wear hats. In that case, if I could search them, I could use the results as reference. I may be able to consider how to wear hats entertainingly.

Comment: Related: [Add ability to see who has a certain hat](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/288865/21960)

Comment: Suggested after [2014](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/246545/259693) and [2015](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/272301/259693) as well. Time for it to be implemented already!

Answer (score 18):

### Community driven hat designs.

We see it all the time. The SE network is community driven (not referring to the [Community](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) user).

Why not hold a contest on [Graphic Design SE](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/) for users there to help create the 2017 WB hats?

There would have to be limitations and you would probably have it only for the normal (not secret) hats, but I think it would give us some fun designs.

Comment: It could probably be done for the secret hats too, as long as you don't give away their triggers.

Comment: @StephenLeppik You could also get trigger ideas from the hat designs.

Comment: In another place, bluefeet has already said that this is the fun and easy part for them. I'm not sure that they will want to pass it to users.

Comment: @Catija Yes, I just saw that (After this answer was written). The idea of leaving the fun part to the SO team makes sense as they also have to do the hard work, but it's jut a suggestion, so we'll see what happens.

Comment: I think it would be fun to see Graphic Design do at least 1-3 of the hats. The SE staff could surely spare that many. :)

Answer (score 15):

#### Soften the "well-received" criteria to include "accepted answer"

Take for example the Lifesaver hat:

> answer a question qualifying for the Tumbleweed badge that gets accepted

Many users get confused when their answer gets accepted but doesn't get the hat.
It's because of another requirement that's not spelled out, that the answer must have positive score, also known more generally as the "well-received" criteria.

The well-received criteria also appeared in the Polymath hat this year,
and it commonly appears in some hats every year.

It would be great if this criteria could be softened to include accepted answers with no votes (that is not the same thing as 0 score).

Answer (score 14):

I would suggest

### Site specific hats:

(of both secret and non secret variety (maybe two of each type?))

Stack Overflow had a site specific hat for documentation. It would be really cool if each site could have a super secret site themed hat decided upon by the moderators on that site.

For example, Math SE could have divide by zero hat, photography could have a cheese hat, etc.

There could also be a hat for getting X secret (or non secret) hats from different sites.

To those who think this is not feasible, the moderators of each site would make a secret hat and design the graphics (in SVG so that they can actually be displayed). Then the community could vote on non secret hat/hats, or the moderators could just choose those as well.

Comment: We did the Stack Overflow only versions because there are features only on that site, and to make the number of hats even everywhere we made two hats non-SO specific. But I think that site specific hats would be difficult to manage especially when we have so many sites.

Comment: @bluefeet what do you mean "manage"? Hats don't really need managing, they're auto awarded once the formula is set. I do agree that having site specific hats for some sites, while not for others won't be fair though.

Comment: @bluefeet That is why the moderaters **of each site** would decide upon the hats. We trust them enough to run the sites, so I think it would be fine for them to choose each hat and its triggers.

Comment: @bluefeet Would it be easier for the hats to each have the same trigger, but just have different images based on the site? I still think it would be a bit insane, but it might be easier than coming up with 160+ different triggers for the hats. Provided people really do want this, anyway.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Manage meaning we have 160+ sites, it would be very difficult to come up with that many unique hats for each site.

Comment: @Kendra they would have to use the same trigger, it's hard enough to come up with triggers for hats in general trying to come up with unique ones for each site would probably take an entire year.  But designing 160+ unique hats would be very difficult IMO.

Comment: @bluefeet so as post author here suggested, let each community decide for itself on its meta site. Surely not all communities will want such a thing, probably around 20 or so, doesn't look that complicated to implement once the details are already given.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Again, I'd think implementing different hats and different triggers on various sites, would be difficult. Not saying no, but I really think it'd be a long shot.

Comment: Your last paragraph isn't that convincing. Coming up with the names and designs of hats is the fun and easy part for us. Coming up with triggers that can actually be implemented, are relevant to the hat, and wouldn't be a resource drain is the painfully boring part. We can't delegate that off to the community easily because it's ultimately up to the developers and we have to sit here and approve, make changes, yada yada before they can be finalized anyways. Pushing the easy part off onto the community doesn't help us all that much.

Comment: @animuson you could have moderators look at past years hats, and make hats based off of them. Or, you could send a hat rule list to the moderators so that you aren't stuck with a bunch of off the wall trigger ideas.

Comment: @10Replies We still have to vet everything for them, make sure that the trigger will work, etc.  Plus, it amplifies the chances of bugs when we have different triggers on every single site.

Comment: I promise you that, while the mods on [blender.se] or [graphicdesign.se] may be excellently capable of creating the artwork for these hats, I don't know that I want to depend on the artistic abilities of the mods on some of the sites I'm a member of. Even on [crafts.se], none of us mods are good at drawing.

Comment: @bluefeet I understand the problem now... I guess the only solution would be to approve a top secret moderator hat trigger creation API where all the possible triggers have been tested extensively... Or just to have the same triggers for each site.

Comment: I think it is not nice to notice you can never win the WB unless you are a user of Overflow. And not all of us can deliver on that site. It would be great if there is also a secret hat somewhere else on the site that has nothing to do with computer capabilities.

Answer (score 14):

## Add hats for moderation

We do have some hats for this like Abominable but there could be more. There should be hats for:

- Successfully taking down spam posts
- Having a certain number of accepted flags - *may be secret due to comments*
- Editing a lot of posts

This would encourage moderation within the community and with the "successful" part to discourage any random flagging, editing, or flagging for spam. Of course, `Abominable` should be kept since it deals with closing and deleting. And of course, over time to prevent an overload of reviews on the first day of WInterbash.

Comment: As long as "editing a lot of posts" means encouraging editing a few posts every day, and not editing a lot all at once, it sounds good to me.

Comment: We've done hats for flagging things in the past and it didn't go over very well, so that won't happen again.

Comment: As a secret hat maybe (if that would reduce abuse)

Comment: @bluefeet Does making something a secret hat reduce abuse? I can understand that it being harder to solve might make fewer people attempt it but all of the testing that occurs to figure out the hat might make it an even bigger target for abuse than if it were a normal hat.

Comment: @Catija Just think of how many accepted flags garnered there will be :)

Comment: @Catija I'd say not really. Users try and figure out what triggers secret hats which can increase some abuse.

Comment: @Floern that's even worse, seeing that people will experiment with secret hats.

Answer (score 14):

#### Include requirements in hat descriptions more precisely

Take for example the Lifesaver hat:

> answer a question qualifying for the Tumbleweed badge that gets accepted

An important requirement was left out there, that the answer must reach a positive score, also known more generally as the "well-received" criteria. 
This can be easily added without making the description too long.

Another example is 011:

> collect 11 hats

It wasn't clear that 11 hats must be earned *on one site*.

---

On the other hand,
it's ok if the description is inaccurate when the real requirements are actually softer. For example all the date-specific hats are awarded within ±12 hours of the date itself, but nobody minds this wasn't mentioned,
as receiving hats unexpectedly is always a pleasant surprise.

Answer (score 13):

## Add a "viral" hat

The general idea would be to create a post associated with one created by either someone with the hat or an arbitrary "starter" user(s) (this will need some thought). I was thinking these criteria:

- post is an answer to a question made by the user with the hat/starter or a question answered by someone with the hat/starter
- post reaches a score of 5 or more
- one or both posts were created during Winter Bash

This would actually encourage users to pay it forward, because the hat can be earned by answering questions, and would reward you with extra attention to your questions.

Answer (score 12):

## Add a hat for consistent voting

Unless I'm missing the point of one or more secret hats, it seems that this year the only hats that rewarded voting have been "Cutting the cord" and the various general participation hats (vote or post: Buche de Noel, Epiphany, I Have a Little Dreidel).

Thus I'd suggest a hat that rewards users for voting (i.e., upvotes and downvotes) throughout the winter bash.  For example:

- Vote five times on posts, on each of ten distinct days
- Vote ten times on posts, on each of five distinct days

I envision these sorts of criteria encouraging a responsible voting habit, which plenty of sites would benefit from.

Comment: Vote on 5 consecutive days?

Comment: @StephenLeppik not a good idea for Christmas / New Year people should spend time away from here

Comment: @Mark people should decide for themselves how to spend their time; not everybody has the same priorities.  Dec 25 is nothing special to some of us.

Comment: I think that 5 votes is almost nothing and 10 not a lot. I often vote maxed out (38 to 41) for one site and a few random votes on other sites. It gives those of us who do not mind getting in a chance on hats where we might not be able to get running ragged or SO hats.

Comment: @Willeke I'm certainly flexible on the criteria, but I wouldn't want people to have a hard time finding things to vote on – if the daily threshold is too high, hat-grabbers might be more inclined to vote without considering the merits of the posts they are voting on.  If it's a smaller number, like 5–10, that sort of issue, though still possible, seems less likely.

Answer (score 12):

### Time is hard, part 2

In an early Winterbash there was a hat for chatting at the turn of the year UTC, +/- something like 5-10 minutes.  That left people in some time zones out, unless they got up in the middle of their night (which at least one person did), and so in future years the time ranges on time-based hats were broadened.  This is why you could earn the "visit on the solstice" hat over about a 36-hour span -- when it was solstice anywhere in the world plus a buffer.

That's the background.  This year when I saw "Like Clockwork" show up I thought "hey, that's a cool-looking hat that I'd like to wear".  And I figured from the name that it had to do with consistent activity.  There are several sites that I'm active on on a daily basis, so I figured whatever the trigger was, I would probably bump into it.

But I didn't, because the hat had a time-constrained requirement on nine consecutive days.  As someone who observes Shabbat, that meant I couldn't satisfy the trigger one day a week.  So that was a bummer.

Shabbat-observant users are a very small proportion of the Stack Exchange community, of course, but it would be great if all hats were theoretically available *to those who want to put in the effort*.  If the range on this hat had been six days instead of nine days, the hat would have been *harder* for the Shabbat-observant to get, but not *impossible*.  ("First Responder" was harder for many of us too because of being on Saturday; that's fine.)  Or if a visit at *any* time in the day would have counted, then it would have been possible in most -- but not all -- time zones.  (It's [possible to earn Fanatic on Mi Yodeya without violating Jewish law](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/7594/472), but you have to choose your dates carefully.)

Again, I recognize that this is a specialized constraint, and -- dare I say it -- *it's only a hat*.  But I humbly request that, for hats that require participation on Saturdays, we try to be flexible.

Comment: Then there is the whole thing of people who observe Sunday. I love this idea, but it could get overly complicated. So I might suggest that the hat triggers get modified for the Mi Yodeya site.

Comment: @CalebKleveter oh, I didn't know that there were those who stay offline for the entirety of Sunday.  My suggestions here aren't day-specific; if the trigger had been "six consecutive days" then people who don't surf on Sunday could presumably do Monday through Saturday, just as those who observe Shabbat could do Sunday through Friday. I don't think site-specific adjustments are the right way to go; first, it adds complexity, and second, it's about the *people* not the *sites*.  People who observe Shabbat don't participate *only* on Mi Yodeya.

Answer (score 11):

## Hats for review tasks

- Awarded when a user successfully passes a review audit.

or

- Awarded when a user completes a task (or a certain amount of tasks) in one of the review queues (and picked the same action as the community consensus).

If that would cause users to robo-review, I'd suggest to make it a secret hat.

Comment: IIRC we've done hats for reviewing before and it resulted in a lot of bad reviews, which lead to a lot of clean-up, so I'm not sure we'd do it again.

Comment: Another option: the hat could be restricted to review audits.

Comment: @Floern do most sites have audits?  I thought only the really big sites got them.  I've never seen one and I'm active on several sites.

Comment: @MonicaCellio I don't even know, I only review things on Stack Overflow. I assumed all sites have audits.

Comment: @MonicaCellio is correct: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237011/which-sites-currently-have-review-audits.

Comment: I proposed [a hat for Skipping](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/270418/168333) once. If that would make robo-reviewers start to robo-Skip instead, I call that a win.

Answer (score 11):

**Win a hat for having at least X hats on 3 different stack exchange sites**

This could be a secret hat, in which case X should be lower - perhaps 5 hats on 3 different sites.

Or it could be a normal hat, in which case X should be higher - perhaps 10 or even 20 hats on 3 different sites (looking at my top 3 hat sites, I have 32/16/16 hats, so I would have made additional effort on two of those sites if we had such a hat with X = 20).

Most users get most of their hats on their single favorite site.
This would encourage users to participate and gain hats on multiple sites.

I'm not sure whether it should be the same X hats on each of the 3 sites, or different hats on different sites.

Answer (score 10):

## Allow us to wear multiple hats

I want to create hat mashups

[image]

Comment: This has actually been [suggested before](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159307/how-about-multiple-hats), and it was declined for performance reasons.

Comment: @RamenChef I have a solution. Start a Kickstarter campaign to help Stack Exchange buy the old military super computer "Road Runner". Use that to handle the WB hats.

Comment: That wouldn't help. The hats are rendered clientside.

Comment: @RamenChef, Thanks for telling me that. My fault that I thought we where talking server side. Suggestion: Add the option that users can turn on. Add a warning that it could adversely affect load time. Then, load the multiple hats only for users that opt in. All other user only see the first hat that the user put on.

Answer (score 10):

#### Make it possible to [distinguish hats earned on current site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245768/distinguishing-hats-earned-on-current-site)

This was requested in many previous years too.

Answer (score 10):

**Eatable hats**

We had cupcakes in past and now taco, but why not some fruits as hat next year like pineapple hat or fruit basket/salad, or my own favorite Kiwi hat.

They can be triggered for helping new users, like editing their posts or upvoting them.

Comment: Perhaps Carmen Miranda?

Answer (score 10):

### Keep site-specific hats but don’t ‘punish’ users not on Stack Overflow

I really liked the idea of having hats that were awarded for participation across non-SO sites. I also thought ‘wow, *What’s up, Doc?* looks like a cool hat’ before I realised it was SO only and I wasn’t able to get it. Why? I’m not anywhere near a programming expert wouldn’t want to attempt to look through sites and sites worth of Documentation just to find typos that I can fix by suggesting edits. If I visit SO, it’s to search for answers and upvote what I found helpful. I’m sure I’m not alone.

That of course means that me not actively participating on SO (for a good reason) implicitly punished me in the overall network-wide hat leaderboard. My maximum possible hat count would have been 39 rather than 41.

Instead, I suggest tying each SO-specific hat to a non-SO-specific hat and counting them as 1 achieved hat. This is already the case for all the other hats: even if you win them on all sites you frequent it will only count once for the leaderboard. Why should the SO-specific hats (and their non-SO counterparts) be any different?

Comment: A secondary suggestion that could be appended is to only allow *wearing* SO-specific hats on SO — but implementing that might mean users accidentally gain access to the non-SO-specific ones outside SO which would not be desirable.

Comment: Although I frequent So and have a decent amount of rep, I had the opposite happen to me. I knew there was no chance of me getting Polymath or Running Ragged because I don't have a large enough skill set to answer very many questions on other sites.

Answer (score 9):

When choosing hat to wear, let us choose on which sites to wear it, instead of just choosing between current site and all sites.

Comment: it is possible, but complicated.

Answer (score 9):

## Change the colors!

Hats are usually distinguishable by their shapes only, without the need of colors due to their... well... distinctive shapes.

[image]

Take my current hat, "Like Clockwork", as an example. You know that it's "Like Clockwork" (or at least not any other hat) due to its simple shape and the clock gear. For my profile, black is suitable but I prefer blue! Changing the color to blue or any basic colors (red, green, yellow, white, etc.) shouldn't be that hard and would add a much more fun spectrum (sorry for the science pun) to hats!

To clarify, let us change the color of the the hat manually.

Comment: My suggestion for using the Pittsburgh Steelers logo for a "stealing" hat would add a lot of color!! :P. Great suggestion, though :)

Comment: Now only if I could still my first answer's score...

Comment: Haha!  Nice!!!! :)

Comment: The Hatter was a perfectly colourful (and great!) hat; the Hero of Questions was also pretty colourful ;) But I’m sensing you *actually* wanted to say ‘give the option of changing monochromic hats’ colours.’

Answer (score 7):

## Make the hat notifications less spammy

With the large number of "post or vote on ..." hats this year, the blue dot in my top bar stayed pretty much constantly lit.

I just counted, and it seems I managed to earn *Where in the World?* 22 times, *Bûche de Noël* 18 times, *I Have A Little Dreidel* 43 times, *Mmmm Bacon* 16 times, *Epiphany* 6 times, and *Just Here for the Hat* a total of 50(!) times.  I'm sure the same thing happened to other people who have accounts on multiple SE sites and like to browser the Hot Network Questions sidebar for interesting questions.

There were a couple of points where I was really close to clicking the "I hate hats" link just to get rid of the annoying notification.

For next year, I have a request: **please only light up the notification icon for *new* hats**, not for the ones that I've already earned on some other site.

Finding out that you've finally managed to hit the rep cap three times in a row is awesome, and deserves a notification.  Finding out that you've clicked the upvote button on *yet another* site during the solstice / Christmas day / Chanukah / New Year's eve / etc. isn't, and doesn't.

Answer (score 6):

With 41 hats this year, I miss the '42'.*

This can be an universal hat, as 42 is the answer to everything, but I would like it to be for those who are not regulars on many sites.
A hat for the new guys/girls who have not learned all the tricks of the trade.

Maybe for getting to have 50 rep on a site, which will exclude all of us long term users who will get 100 extra on joining a new site. (Yes, that does exclude me.)

While it is not impossible for someone to start as 'new user' at the start of WB to also earn most or even all of the other hats, it would be very unlikely for someone to be able to get all hats, even less likely to win all on one site.

PS. For those who don't get it, 42 as in the [Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hitchhikers-guide) by Douglas Adams.

*-It turns out there were 42 hats, the day and night hats counted as two separate ones. Still, I feel that there are not really 42 as the day/night were given for the same reason and at the same time.

Comment: Instead of just 50 rep, trying adding notable achievements such as a positive score question, answer, and comment.

Comment: I did pick a thing that is only available for new users who do not have accounts elsewhere. It can be any amount of Rep below 100, as long as users got it by positive action, not by negative action.

Comment: I could simply add a bounty of 50 rep to bypass this

Comment: @Mithrandir just for future reference, "random edits" is not a good [suggested edit description](http://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/48625).  Please elaborate on how your edits helps the post (improves grammar, etc).

Comment: @PythonMaster, my point here is that the hat would ONLY be available for people who are new to Stack Exchange. Whether they earn it by 2 rep at a time working hard on approved edits, or by being lucky with one good answer. Or by winning one bounty.

Comment: "Reach 100 rep by asking and/or answering questions"?  This excludes edits, but people brand new to SE (no association bonus) probably aren't best off starting with edits anyway.  It does allow bounties, but how concerned should we be about somebody standing up a sock just to transfer rep to it to get the sock a hat?  That seems pretty limited.

Comment: We could make it a thing that the hat can not be transfered, so people can earn the hat for their own pleasure if they make a sock, but can not win all hats on one account.

Answer (score 5):

### Badge Giver Hat

Being the one that, with an upvote, makes a question or answer to hit 10 (Nice Q/A), 25 (Good Q/A) or 100 (Great Q/A) score, hence giving a badge for someone.

Answer (score 3):

### Secret Hat For Editing a Hidden Gem “Question”

Similar to the description in the [late answers review task](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152084/examples-of-hidden-gems-in-late-answers) but with a twist.

The hat would be earned for anyone who edited a -3 question which subsequently earned four upvotes.

First, it shows that LQQs can sometimes be drastically improved/saved with a good edit. Secondly, it's important that the edit is not done for egoistic purposes, e.g. wanting to post an answer on a question  that was deliberately "tailor-made". Lastly, if the editor upvotes the question, I don't find anything wrong with that. It just means they saw a potential gem hiding among the "garbage".

Comment: Would it be better if the question reached a score of 4 instead

Comment: It's really rare that a -3 question can earn +7 upvotes, I think earning +4 or +5 votes is *possible* if the edit is spot on. You want something achievable in order to earn a hat not a miracle ☺ This is from an EL&U viewpoint.

Comment: Or maybe just positive

Answer (score 3):

## FINISH HIM<sup>1</sup>

A hat for dealing the *killing blow* (5th Close Vote) to a question.

While not an issue on main sites such as StackOverflow, other sites (e.g. WorldBuilding) often see questions getting much attention even though they do not fit the format and thus further encourage questions that are off-topic.
Such a hat would (hopefully) encourage people with enough reputation to more liberally apply their VTC rights.

<sub><sup>1</sup>*Him, Her, Them, It, Us, ...*</sub>

Comment: On Aviation.SE people are already quite liberal with their VTC rights. I'd rather not encourage that!

Answer (score 3):

## Consolation Prize

A(nother) bounty-based hat idea. We had a hat this year for awarding a bounty on the final day, but what if you don't get an answer at all, or at least not anything <strike>worthy</strike> eligible for the automatic-bounty awarding? In other words:

**What if the bounty expires with no winning answer?**

According to the Help Page on Bounties:

> If you do not award the bounty within 24 hours of the bounty period ending, half the bounty value will be automatically awarded to the top voted answer posted after the bounty start, provided it has a score of at least 2. If no new answer matches this requirement, no reputation will be awarded at all, and the reputation used on the bounty will be lost forever.

So the requirements for the badge would be:

> #### Consolation Prize
>
> Start a bounty in Winterbash that expires without a winning answer (not manually awarded and no answer >= 2 total score).

Why I think this hat would work well:

- **Hard to game:** Your can't just raise a bounty and then not award it. Other people's votes will ensure that at least some of the bounty is awarded to people that try to answer the question. You can also only raise 3 bounties per-site at one time, so the 'shotgun' approach won't work either.
- **Semi-random:** It's not something you can just work towards, like 'Edit 5 posts' or 'Close and Reopen' a question. It's a little bit luck-based (or unlucky if you consider the fact you didn't get an answer).
- **The Spirit of Giving:** Like all previous bounty hats, it rewards those who are willing to give and it helps get eyeballs and answers on questions.
- **Low entry fee**: You need 75 rep to raise a bounty, compared to 2000 for non-suggested editing hats or 3000 for closing/reopening hats.

This could also work well as a secret hat, making it harder to game.

Answer (score 2):

#### Viral hats

Seed a couple of these at random (or infect the CMs) then award them for up-voting someone who already has the hat.

Result: up-votes all around!

Comment: This has been suggested already: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/289357/278543

Comment: @PythonMaster I don't know how I missed that. Different trigger, though.

Comment: This hat would encourage drive-by votes and probably vote fraud and moderators getting swarmed by rep caps for Winter Bash. I prefer mods work for their rep :)

Answer (score 2):

*[Inspired by this earlier post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/288493/244062)*

#### Change the "Maverick" from a non-secret to a secret hat.

As we've seen some concerns about the behaviour triggered by the criteria of this particular hat, maybe the criteria can be *slightly modified* (*the present criteria is already known*) and the hat can be made a "secret" hat. This way

1. The possibility of alleged "gaming" the system would be less.
2. There would not be much space for doubting the actual quality of the Q/A.

Comment: A version of this hat was already a secret hat last year (I don't remember if the trigger was exactly the same). And trying to figure out the exact trigger of a secret hat may result in much more "gaming" than winning regular hats (especially last year, when figuring the trigger of a secret hat gave you an additional manual hat).

Comment: @Eran I don't disagree, but IMHO, the amount of users involved in finding the trigger of a secret hat is much less compared to the number of users trying to achieve a non-secret hat. Also, I support the idea of dropping the "Eureka" hat, just FYI. Most of the secret hats should come "naturally" based on the actions. Testing for the trigger of secret hat are also sometimes useful, like editing old questions, removing old comments (mostly noise, IMHO) etc. Just my two cents.

Answer (score 2):

### Selfless / Mask of Zorro "Hat"

- Edit an answer to a question where your own answer already got accepted; this answer should already have two upvotes when you edit it.
- The answer you improved becomes the new "accepted answer".

This *can* be a secret hat but doesn't need to be.

Comment: I fear that may contribute to users posting low quality (though correct) fast answers. What's the point in editing another answer with what you should have posted in the first place? I'd like to see a mask of zorro design though!

Comment: @Mariano 1. The edit to the other answer doesn't need to involve adding content from your own answer. 2. How would you define a correct answer that is of low quality?

Comment: 1. I see your point, but I don't see how this would be awarded for things you regularly do on the site. 2. I was referring to a code only or "try this" answer.

Comment: @Mariano To address your second comment, I added the condition that the edited answer needs to have two upvotes. I hope that helps against spamming with low-quality answers to game the system.

Answer (score 0):

## Give us a site to test the hats.

Don't get rid of secret hats, just give us a place to test them. If we had a site for testing, such as [Winter Bash 2017 Secret Hat Testing site](http://2017hattest.stackexchange.com), that would remove soul-selling for hats.

The only downside would be that we can't test secret hats on old questions here. But I think it's worth it for any other triggers.

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing a hat for nearly every feature, like editing 5 old questions (Werewolf Hunter), cleaning up comments after post owner edit (It's a me), removing 10 unnecessary comments from 2017 (This is Fine), Vote 7 times from app (Too cool), etc.

Should we have one for cleaning up downvotes, which should be removed when post owner edited legitimately? As the downvoter won't get notification as he didn't comment (if I am not wrong) and the owner cannot ping the downvoter to get revision?

This will motivate someone to revisit & revert their downvotes.

Comment: This question is for **this current** event. At the end of the event, we post a new one for the following year (2018), this should be posted there.

Answer (score -3):

## What *is* my hat rank?

At the moment, you can go to the hat leader boards and see who has the most hats. But I can't see what my rank is. Sure there is a number that I get, but there a bunch of other people with that number also. Why?

I am not sure how that ranking works on the hat leaderboards, but I think it would be better to have the leaderboard work like the [site wide rep leaderboard](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/alltime/stackoverflow). With everyone getting their own rank.

### Update:

I now know how the leaderboards work. Should we make it so ranks are first come first serve? That way we only have one user for each rank.

Comment: A bunch of other people have that number because they have the same number of hats as you. With rep, that's mostly a non-issue.  You could possibly rank them by rarest hats but that's a bit wiggly and  prone to changes.

Comment: @EᴀsᴛᴇʀʟʏIʀᴋ What causes the large gaps in rank numbers?

Comment: When 2 people are tied for 2nd, then the next person is automatically placed at 4th (because 2nd and 3rd are "taken up" by the 2 people tied).

Comment: That would be a little unfair... they got the same number of hats and should earn the same rank. 1st place is all that matters anyways :)

Comment: Would this maybe work with the hat leader for that particular site getting a "special" top hat earning hat?  Perhaps go by rep if there's a tie for the top spot.  I don't know how that would work or triggering it, but I think that would be cool and kind of "bragging rights."  Just a suggestion :)

Answer (score -4):

## A hat for spending the holidays off the network

This year we had a hat for posting something on the chat on the New Year.

What about having a hat for spending some of the holidays off the network/site.

E.g. a hat that would be awarded to someone that *spends* at least *3 consecutive days* without logging into (any) Stackexchange site?

---

How to award this hat:

UserXYZ is online on day 1. They are then offline for days 2, 3 and 4. They come online again on day 5 and get the hat.

Comment: That defeats the purpose of Winterbash. You might as well award a hat for not participating in Winterbash.

Comment: @Eran your proposal, an example of overt extremeness, would indeed defeat any purpose of a reward for balancing people's consumption of digital media and similar. The idea I proposed is meant to get people to think before mindlessly chasing *yet another medal*...

Comment: _a hat that would be awarded to someone that spends at least 3 consecutive days without logging into (any) Stackexchange site_ - you do realize that would greatly inflate the number of hats awarded, right?  People who are no longer active on the site would get a hat. The purpose of hats is to do things on the site. If you want to take 3 days, then feel free but I don't think we'll award a hat for it.

Comment: I'm going to point out that this idea could distress hardcore hat collectors who are moderators or have rolls that require them to be available.

Comment: @bluefeet thanks for the pointer. I actually forgot to write down half my thoughts it seems..

Answer (score -16):

#### Make the hunt for secret hats bit easier

Give the names of all secret hats in advance, either in the blog annoucement or in the Winterbash site itself. No clues, just the names.

At least for me, if I would hunt for secret hats, knowing the names before someone else get them first would also be an incentive.

Comment: No! We want mysteries because we feel more accomplished and feel like we can do anything

Comment: IMHO, the names didn't really help during this WB (my first), and on top of that I would actually want it *to be a secret*...